# How to fetch contact list from Gmail using xmpp framework

Tags: gmail, xmpp, chat, nsxml

I am trying to make a chat application. I am using XMPP framework to fetch the contact list from Gmail account. I am able to receive chat buddies, but I want all the contacts from my gmail account. I want to retrieve all contacts instead of only chat buddies.

How can I do this? I am new to xmpp framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try here:

http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/